# I randomly got a corrupted DLC which I didn't buy?

Tags: just-dance-2

I was playing Just Sweat when I noticed an interesting song - Crying Blood by V V Brown. I never bought this song, so I thought maybe the game glitched and I received a DLC for free. The cover was very low resolution, and when I went to play it, the game said "the song could not be loaded because the data is corrupted."

I went to Archives under Extras, and it wasn't there. When I went back to the song menu, it was gone.

Does anybody know why this happened?

EDIT: Apparently the same thing happened in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZEnvwndgxwc) with Futebol Crazy. A person in the comments said they also had the same thing with Crying Blood, but I still couldn't figure out why it happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a random glitch.

I can't find any reason why, it just happens sometimes.

I do notice that in my case and the video, DLCs were downloaded, so maybe the game thought I had one DLC when I really had another.